# Xcode Document Based Application Save FIile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, save, file-format, document-based

So I was messing around with the Document Based Application, and I'm trying get the save file to work. I have a file format save to .lgre and whenever I hit save, I'll select  location, and then nothing happens except that I get this in that console. Can someone tell me whats going wrong?

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c64b64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8e9ca6de objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c64b4fd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Ligre UI                            0x00000001000011b1 -[Document dataOfType:error:] + 129
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff933d8fcf -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] + 861
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff933dbf03 -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] + 494
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff933dae6b -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:forceTemporaryDirectory:error:] + 850
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff933dbb93 -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 28
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff933dbd01 -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] + 357
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff933e8fc5 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_22307 + 240
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff933e8ec6 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke2304 + 365
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff933e72e6 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke2176 + 1587
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff93426882 __62-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _onMainThreadInvokeWorker:]_block_invoke1881 + 175
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c56954c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c55b655 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c55b196 __CFRunLoopRun + 1814
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c55a838 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9421243f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff942121ba ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff94211ffb _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff92fbe6d1 _DPSNextEvent + 964
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff92fbde80 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff92fb1e23 -[NSApplication run] + 594
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff92f9d2d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
24  Ligre UI                            0x0000000100001302 main + 34
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8cea45c9 start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override dataOfType or one of the writeToURL methods?

See the discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/dataOfType:error: